# Python Excel PixelArt bot

Tags: python, excel

so I made a bot which "draws" a given picture in Microsoft Excel pixel by pixel and it works fine for smaller photos (something about 500x500 i'd say) but when I give it a bigger picture the excel file says it is corrupted and simply doesn't work, any ideas? Also, sorry the variables are in polish but i hope it doesn't really matter, if you have any questions about them i will answer in the comments, its also my second post here so do not roast me too hard, thanks!

here's the code:

```
import time
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from PIL import Image

plik = "1.xlsx"
fota = "fb.png"

start = time.time()

zdj = Image.open(fota)
zdj_rgb = zdj.convert("RGB")
szer, wys = zdj.size

wb = load_workbook(plik)
ws = wb.active

def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    return '%02x%02x%02x' % rgb

def excel_col(col):
    
    quot, rem = divmod(col-1,26)
    return excel_col(quot) + chr(rem+ord('A')) if col!=0 else ''

for y in range(wys):
    for x in range(szer):

        yy = y+1

        komorka = str(excel_col(x+1) + str(yy))

        pixel_rgb = zdj_rgb.getpixel((x, y))
        
        rgb = "00" + str(rgb_to_hex((pixel_rgb[0], pixel_rgb[1], pixel_rgb[2])))

        rgbFill = PatternFill(start_color=rgb,
                end_color=rgb,
                fill_type='solid')

        ws[komorka].fill = rgbFill

end = time.time()

minuty, sekundy = divmod((end-start), 60)

print(f"Renderowanie zajelo {minuty} minut/y i {round(sekundy)} sekund.")

wb.save(plik)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe your bigger image is really corrupted? Did you check if you can open it in other tools - like image viewer?